# Texture coordintes for a polygon and a square texture

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, opengl, texture-mapping

basically I have a texture. I also have a lets say octagon (or any polygon). I find that octagon's bounding box. Let's say my texture is the size of the octagon's bounding box. How could I figure out the texture coordinates so that the texture maps to it. To clarify, lets say you had a square of tin foil and cut the octagon out you'd be left with a tin foil textured polygon.I'm just not sure how to figure it out for an arbitrary polygon. Thanks

Comment: How is your polygon defined? If they have any sort of coordinates, I'm sure you can figure out a mapping from object space to texture space.

Comment: yes they are vectors reletive to (0,0) (upper left corner) im not sure the figure out part though,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Texture mapping an NGon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2789545/texture-mapping-an-ngon).